# How to draw chess board pattern with Brush on Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I got `Canvas` and some `Rectangles` of different `width` but same `height`.
I draw  `Rectangles` on `Canvas` pragramticaly, `width` calculated in real time when i draw it.

Some of `Rectangles` have `SolidColorBrush` but rest should look like chess board:

[image]

I tried to do it like this:

```
private static Brush CreateBrush()
{

    // Create a DrawingBrush
    var blackBrush = new DrawingBrush();
    // Create a Geometry with white background

    // Create a GeometryGroup that will be added to Geometry
    var gGroup = new GeometryGroup();
    gGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 10, 10)));
    gGroup.Children.Add(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(10, 10, 10, 10)));
    // Create a GeomertyDrawing
    var checkers = 
        new GeometryDrawing(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), null, gGroup);

    var checkersDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();

    checkersDrawingGroup.Children.Add(checkers);

    blackBrush.Drawing = checkersDrawingGroup;

    // Set Viewport and TileMode
    blackBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5 );
    blackBrush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;

    return blackBrush; 
}
```

As far as `Rectangles` got different size, same DrawingBrush looks different on different `Rectangles` - its not repeats to fill it, but stretch.

As i understand, the problem is in `blackBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5 );` - i should set diffrent `Viewports` according to each `Rectangle` `width`, but its no acceptable for me. I need to use one brush for all rectangles of different size and texture should look like one picture - same scale for X and Y, but it can repeat many time in one `Rectangle`

Maybe there is another Brush type or other way to solve this issues?

Fill free to ask, if my post was unclear, also sorry for my english.

add picture for what i need:
[image]
(It's not about width, its about texture fill)

Comment: *rest should look like chessfield*... like what now? Please use sensible descriptions.

Comment: @Sheridan i add picture to explain, sorry dont know better word.

Comment: Ahhh... chess board. I have edited your question accordingly. However, I still don't understand your problem... it seems as though you have created your chess board pattern successfully. What exactly *is* your problem?

Comment: @Sheridan, ty i add picture to illustrate how my Rectangles looks now, and how i want it to look. I want same texture without deformations and strech, but just repeat same pattern to cover all Rectangle.

Comment: Unfortunately the `DrawingBrush` doesn't have the useful `SpreadMethod` property that the `LinearGradientBrush` has, so we can't repeat it in the same way. However, the real problem that you face is that the pattern of a `DrawingBrush` will stretch along with the size of the shape that uses it... as you found out yourself. There *must* be some way to do it though... keep looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `Viewport` settings, you should set its `ViewportUnits` to `Absolute` instead of `RelativeToBoundingBox` (as by default):

```
//we have to use a fixed size for the squares
blackBrush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, 60, 60);
blackBrush.Viewport.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
```

Here is an example showing the checkboard using pure XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,60,60" 
                                      ViewportUnits="Absolute">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" 
                    Geometry="M5,5 L0,5 0,10 5,10 5,5 10,5 10,0 5,0 Z"/>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>            
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a DrawingGroup with King King's answer, you can specify different colors for each side:

```
<DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    <DrawingGroup>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black" Geometry="M5,5 L0,5 0,10 5,10 5,5 10,5 10,0 5,0 Z"/>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="Blue" Geometry="M0,0 L0,5 0,10 0,5, 10,5 10,10 5,10 5,0 Z"/>
    </DrawingGroup>
</DrawingBrush.Drawing>
```